# animate.css giving a specific delay with className

Tags: animate.css

```html
 <h3 class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft animate__delay-1s 1s"> Test </h3>
```

```html
 <h3 class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft animate__delay-0.5s 0.5s"> Test </h3>
```

First one working but when i give a 0.5s its not working.  Why we can not give a specific delay? Do you have any idea, if you help me i will be glad.

Answer (score 0):

The delay below 1 second is not possible with `class name`

for shorter and longer delays you can use `--animate-delay` property in css

**Eg:-**

```
#myHeading {
  --animate-delay: 0.5s;
}
```

read [here](https://animate.style/#utilities) for more info.